# API con Ruby on rails

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails

Hola a toda la comunidad.
Me estoy iniciando en ruby on rails y me surgió el siguiente inconveniente al crear un nuevo proyecto tipo API. El comando que ejecute desde la consola es

```
rails new apiDemo --api
```

ejecuto `bundle intall` pero al llegar a la gema `bootsnap` me genera el siguiente error

```
Fetching bootsnap 1.4.4
Installing bootsnap 1.4.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190503-10368-oxk560.rb
extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR="
generating bootsnap-i386-mingw32.def
compiling bootsnap.c
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_cache_path':
bootsnap.c:245:3: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
[-Wformat]
bootsnap.c:245:3: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_rb_fetch':
bootsnap.c:286:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
[-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
bootsnap.c: In function 'fetch_cached_data':
bootsnap.c:412:3: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of
data type [-Wtype-limits]
bootsnap.c: In function 'atomic_write_cache_file':
bootsnap.c:484:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mkstemp'
[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_rb_fetch':
bootsnap.c:632:13: warning: 'output_data' may be used uninitialized in this
function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
bootsnap.c:603:9: note: 'output_data' was declared here
linking shared-object bootsnap/bootsnap.so
bootsnap.o: In function `atomic_write_cache_file':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bootsnap-1.4.4\ext\bootsnap/bootsnap.c:484:
undefined reference to `mkstemp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bootsnap.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/bootsnap-1.4.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.4.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  bootsnap
```

y no me deja continuar.
Intente también instalar la gema por separado haciendo `gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`. y me da el mismo error si intento instalar alguna de las verciones anteriores.
Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿qué versión de ruby utilizas?

Comment: ruby 2.3.3 y Rails 5.2.3

Comment: ¿has probado con [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516598/895789)? ¿puedes agregar a tu pregunta  el cómo agregaste la gema en tu `Gemfile`?

Comment: Por último (y creo que más importante), si te estás iniciando en rails ¿es necesario que veas el usar una gema como `bootsnap`?. En general, una gema de optimización la llegarías a usar en una etapa de escalado de tu app, que sería cuando esté en producción y tenga una carga suficiente que amerite su uso e implementación. Y si, el conocimiento nunca está demás, pero si estás en una etapa de aprendizaje, creo que estás dejando de lado lo importante (que es aprender rails) por resolver problemas de algo que eventualmente nunca llegues a usar. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, solucione el problema eliminando la gema del `gemfile ` y comentando una linea en el archivo `config/boot.rb` `require 'bootsnap/setup'`